# How to best train SVM on images with different aspect ratio

Tags: svm

Can the SVM work on data with different dimensions? (using libsvm)
If the images have different size, I can resize to a standard value. 
But if they have different aspect ratios, it seems not to make sense to resize without keeping the original aspect ratio. 
Or shall I pad the images with zeros to make them have the same aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0):

> Can the SVM work on data with different dimensions?

No it can't, but you already give an answer about how to overcome that (resizing the images).

> But if they have different aspect ratios, it seems not to make sense to resize without keeping the original aspect ratio. Or shall I pad the images with zeros to make them have the same aspect ratio?

Agreed, not maintaining the aspect ratio just would make the problem even harder. Usually people pre-process all the images to one aspect ratio and use letterboxing or pillarboxing when necessary.